# Protocol 'Numeric' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the following swift code that was written by a colleague.

I don't know swift.

I've been running 'Product' -> 'Archive' in xcode so that I can release to the App Store.

The following code has been in place for a long time and I haven't changed it, but I'm now getting the error "Protocol 'Numeric' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

Does anyone know what the issue is? ...and could you explain it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import Foundation

func MyCallback(_ id: String, _ with: Any?) -> String{
    return "My.callback('\(id)', \(with != nil ? with is Numeric ? with! : "'\(with!)'" : "void 0"));"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO at a glance this code looks really bad. This is not how you unwrap optionals in Swift. Anyway if `with` is a `Numeric` type or a `String` you can simply try to cast it as a `String` instead of checking if it is `Numeric`.

```
func MyCallback(_ id: String, _ with: Any?) -> String {
    if let string = with as? String {
        return "My.callback('\(id)', '\(string)');"
    } else if let with = with {
        return "My.callback('\(id)', \(with));"
    }
    return "My.callback('\(id)', void 0);"
}
```

Note that it is Swift naming convention to name your methods starting with a lowercase letter `func myCallback`.